# How to transfer String from Java to JS?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I use [JsBridge](https://github.com/lzyzsd/JsBridge) library for data transfer from android activity to webview with JS. 
I'm sending string via method

> webView.send("hello");

In the console I see

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "{"data":"hello"}", source: 
>   file:///android_asset/demo.html

How can I get a "hello" from the data in demo.html as a text resource?

Answer (score 0):

```
var string="{\"data\":\"hello\"}";
var json=JSON.parse(string);
console.log(json.data);// 'hello'
```

Here are demo codes from https://github.com/lzyzsd/JsBridge/blob/master/example/src/main/assets/demo.html

```
function connectWebViewJavascriptBridge(callback) {
    if (window.WebViewJavascriptBridge) {
        callback(WebViewJavascriptBridge)
    } else {
        document.addEventListener(
            'WebViewJavascriptBridgeReady'
            , function() {
                callback(WebViewJavascriptBridge)
            },
            false
        );
    }
}

connectWebViewJavascriptBridge(function(bridge) {
    bridge.init(function(message, responseCallback) {
        console.log('JS got a message', message);
        var data = {
            'Javascript Responds': '测试中文!'
        };
        console.log('JS responding with', data);
        responseCallback(data);
    });
})
```

`message` is what you want.

Comment: u parse just var string, not data from console

Comment: So you want to read something from console? Console is for showing logs, not for code reading. I think the sample code in JsBridge is clear enough to understand.